# Nesting presentational / container components and re-usability

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm getting really confused / unsure about the way I'm writing my presentational / container components. Especially when nesting multiple ways deep. I would love some thoughts on how I can be better at separating these concerns.

The following is my (relevant) redux state when combined (very simplified).

```
{
    questions: [ // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
        {
            id: 1,
            questionAnswers: [ // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                {
                    id: 1,
                    question: 'some question',
                    amount: 10 // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                },

                {
                    id: 2,
                    question: 'some question',
                    amount: 10 // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                }
            ]
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            questionAnswers: [ // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                {
                    id: 3,
                    question: 'some question',
                    amount: 10 // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                },

                {
                    id: 4,
                    question: 'some question',
                    amount: 10 // Need to get fetched from redux via selector
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

So currently I created the following components to render this with the correct data, which works fine.

**Page component**

```
const Page1 = () => ({
    <QuestionList />
});
```

**QuestionList (container)**

```
// Gets all questions from the store
const QuestionList = ({ questions }) => ({
    {questions.map(question => <Question question={question} />)}
});
```

**Question (container)**

```
// Gets all questionAnswers for a question from the store
const Question = ({ question, questionAnswers }) => ({
    <div>
        <h3>The question itself</h3>
        <div>{questionAnswers.map(answer => <QuestionAnswer answer={answer} />)}</div>
    </div>
});
```

**QuestionAnswer (container)**

```
// Gets the amount for each QuestionAnswer from the store
const QuestionAnswer = ({ answer, amount }) => ({
    <div>
        <div>{answer}</div> 
        <div>{amount}</div>
    </div>
});
```

The problem comes when I want to reuse the `questionList` component with different data from the store. How would I best tackle this? Should I connect all data to the top level `QuestionList` in stead of the `QuestionAnswer` and make all the child component presentational ones? This feels so weird as it would need to contain all the `questions`, `questionAnswers` and `questionAnswer amounts`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think you are on the right track with your thinking. Instead of having `QuestionList` make the request for questions, the `Page` component should be requesting the data and then pass that in as props to `QuestionList` like `<QuestionList questions={this.state.questions} />`. That way, you can reuse `QuestionList` anywhere and just give it the data you care about.

Comment: Thanks! But how to deal with the state that is fetched inside the bottom level component aka `QuestionAnswer` :/ I'll guess I need to rewrite the whole thing as it is mega confusing now.